Connectivity of a induced map between homotopy pullbacks
Consider cospans of continuous maps $A\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow }C\stackrel{g}{\leftarrow }B$ and $A'\stackrel{f'}{\rightarrow }C'\stackrel{g'}{\leftarrow }B'$ along with maps $\alpha :A\to A'$, $\beta :B\to B'$ and $\gamma :C\to C'$ that make the corresponding diagram homotopy commutative.
It is well-known that if $\alpha $ and $\beta $ are $n$-equivalences and $\gamma $ is an $(n+1)$-equivalence, then the induced map between the corresponding homotopy pullbacks $A\times ^h_CB\to A'\times ^h_{C'}B'$ is an $n$-equivalence.
Is there a specific reference (book, paper) where I can find the proof of this fact? Or, at least, a clue for the proof?
By a q-equivalence I mean a map inducing isomorphisms of homotopy groups in degree <q and epimorphims in degree q, for every choice of base point.

Hi Jose! Have a look at the discussion at  https://mathoverflow.net/q/132339/8103. It's possible that the books of May-Ponto or Strom mentioned there have this statement.

To a homotopy pullback is associated the fibration sequence $\Omega C\rightarrow A\times_C^hB\rightarrow A\times B$ with the obvious maps. Look at the long exact sequence in homotopy and use the homomorphisms induced by the maps $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ to compare the sequences coming from the different homotopy pullbacks.

Thanks, Mark. Unfortunately, the statement does not appear in these books. However, the discussion is very interesting.

Thanks, Tyron. It seems that your argument could work well. However, wouldn't there be any problems with the part of the sequence that's not involving groups and homomorphisms?
